# Can't understand this MySQL Query Purpose

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing an internship as Web Developer,  I'm a bit new and i'm here to ask your experience to clarify my doubts; while i was working on a website that someone else made i found this query:

```
$query = "SELECT a.upload_date, a.zipfile, a.lang, b.*
          FROM something_uploadform as a , something2_stayinformed as b
          WHERE a.uid_head =b.uid and a.zipfile<>'' order by ".$orderby." desc";
```

Can anyone help me to understand it? I thought that this piece of code picks a record and attach it to an a, isn't it?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Why should this attach anything? Looks to me like a simple implicit `JOIN`.

Comment: Good luck with your internship. I'm sure it will be a valuable experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a high level, this query is doing an implicit `JOIN` on two tables. Let's break it down:

The data is coming from two tables (*`AS` gives the table an alias*):

- `something_uploadform` as "a" (this table will now be known as `a`)
- `something2_stayinformed` as "b" (this table will now be known as `b`)

The columns being selected:

- `a.upload_date`
- `a.zipfile`
- `a.lang`
- `b.*` (All columns in table `b`)

The tables are being joined on the columns:

- `a.uid_head = b.uid`

The filter being applied:

- `a.zipfile <> ''` (where the column `zipfile` is not empty)

The sort being applied:

- `$orderby DESC` (passed variable, sorted in descending order)

Answer (score 1):

`something_uploadform as a` defines `a` as an alias for `something_uploadform` so you don't have to specify the full table name when selecting columns.